# Set padding-top for scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I know there is already a Question like this. But I can't use margin-top as a solution.
I have a Sidebar where I set the padding-top to 10vh so it is displayed under the navbar.
My Sidebar has many elements, so a scrollbar is necessary. But the top part the scrollbar is hidden by the navbar. Does someone know how I could solve this problem?

I already tried to work with margin-top but then my sidenav items are displayed below the bottom of the page and I didn't find a solution for this issue. 
I also tried to use ::-webkit-scrollbar but it seems like this doesn't work with padding.

Here you can see the code of my problem:

```js
function openNav() {

        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "30%";


}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.navbar{
    height: 35vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    padding-top: 35vh;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" onclick="openNav()">Open sidenav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" onclick="closeNav()">Close sidenav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <div class="SNHeader">
        <br>
        <h4>Categories:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="repeat">
            <ul>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add an example in stackblitz? It is very difficult give a solution with no code.

Comment: Could try `position: relative; top: 20px;` but difficult to know what will work when not given any code.

Comment: @beanic
I added the code.

Comment: @eyl327 Thanks for your idea. I can't use it unfortunately.  If you have any other idea I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I just set the height of the sidebar to 90vh (100vh - Navbar height = 90vh) and set top to 10vh. that way the navbar won't be displayed under the main content.

```js
function openNav() {

        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "30%";


}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.navbar{
    height: 35vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    height: 65vh;
    width: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.7s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" onclick="openNav()">Open sidenav</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" onclick="closeNav()">Close sidenav</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
    <div class="SNHeader">
        <br>
        <h4>Categories:</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="repeat">
            <ul>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
                <li>Blah</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```